# $window.location.href not working sporadically, it is working if I restart browser

Tags: angular-ui-router, redirect, window.location

My below code is stop working sporadically. It is not able to redirect to specific page (in this case landing page after successful login ). Using 1.2x Angular.

`$window.location.href = (prefix ? prefix : '') + data.redirect;`

It is not redirecting untill restarting the browser or clearing cookies and cache.

Even I added code to clear cookies and cache, still issue not resolved. Is it angular issue?  When I debug the code, it is going to **angular.js** and from there it is redirecting back to application login page instead landing page of application.

Comment: I think you don't need the $... so use window.location.href = (prefix ? prefix : '') + data.redirect;

Comment: Nope, it is not working. I tried with below lines of code also. no luck.    window.location = (prefix ? prefix : '') + data.redirect;  And     
 document.location = (prefix ? prefix : '') + data.redirect;